# Find / Search Excel with multiple conditions in MS Excel

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have been trying to get this issue resolved but finally felt need to come to super masters of stackoverflow.

I am putting record with hyphens and without hyphens in excels cells, and want to get updated if there is any duplicate number been put. GatePass and Voucher number are been put in 2 columns

Gatepass is only one number, but Voucher numbers could be one or two or more than that within the one cell so i use hyphen to separate them. now what i am trying to do is

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(C$2:C2,C3)>0,COUNTIF(D$2:D2,SEARCH("-",D$2:D2)-1)>D3),"D-GPV",IF(COUNTIF(C$12:C12,C13)>0,"Dup-V",IF(COUNTIF(D$12:D12,SEARCH("-",D$12:D12)-1)>D3,"Dup-GP","")))
```

to get this result given in the image
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

So, I want if GP is duplicate then Dup-GP or if Voucher is duplicate then Dup-V, or if both are duplicates then D-GPV

Where i will put full record in voucher cells like, 141-142-143-144 instead of 141-144

[image]

Please help

P-s, I want simple formula instead of VB Code and i am using MS Office 2007

Comment: 1.  which cell is C12? 2. what is the issue with the formula you tried? ( is it error or working partially?)

Comment: @p._phidot_ it only works for the Duplicate Gatepass but not for the Voucher column

Comment: Refering to your new screenshot, the L11 mentioned repeated gate pass & voucher.. For gate pass is ok, but voucher 141 & 155 had never appeared in c2:c10. | So L11 should be Dup-GP right?

Comment: @p._phidot_ voucher number 141 is already in C2, i did not notice the c2 was not taken in screen shot due to freeze panes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Excel 2019 Formula:*

Assuming your data starts at `A1`, enter this formula in `L2` and copy downwards.

```
=CHOOSE( SUM( 1,
     IFERROR( IF( SEARCH( $C2, TEXTJOIN( "-", 1, $C$1:$C1 ) ), 1 ), 0 ),
     IF( COUNTIF( $D$1:$D1, $D2 ) > 0, 2, 0 ) ), TEXT(,), "Dup-V", "Dup-GP", "Dup-GVP" )
```

[image]

Comment: I feel sorry for me because i am still using office 2007, So TEXTJOIN is not gonna work as it was introduced within MS Office 2016.

Comment: @Mian You just changed the picture, what makes you think that will help you? It seems that you have two options:  1. Have a separated line for each `Voucher` number in the table, then a formula can be built to show both duplications; you will be able to group all  `Vouchers` for the `Gate Pass`\`Production` combination using a `Pivottable`.  and 2. Upgrade to at least Excel 2016.

Comment: Sir, may be understanding the question was not easy due to my question briefing quality. let me explain it again. The solution given by you finds the Gatepass nicely, but it only finds the duplicate voucher if the Duplicate Voucher number is entered all alone. in case of putting more than 1 vouchers in a cell and it includes any duplicate voucher number then this solution does not work. e.g:- in next cell if i put voucher number 163-164-150 here 150 voucher number is duplicate, but the formula will not catch it. I got Office 365

Comment: Unfortunately I can not look into this now as I'm working on a project and have no free time now. I'll look into this as soon as I have some free time.

Comment: Sure, Sir, i ll be waiting for solution. If you can tag someone who can sort it out plz do this favor. Thanks a bunch